# ZXingScannerView not showing live feed, but is scanning

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using ZxingScannerView in Xamarin Forms iOS, but my live feed isn't showing.  The view is scanning, because when I point my camera at a QR-code, my ScanResultCommand is hit and the correct value is show.
But it's hard to point the camera exactly when you're not seeing anything.

I tried two methods, like putting my ZXingSannerView in Xaml and in Code, but the result stays the same.  The view is scanning, but I don't see live feed from the camera.

```
<zxing:ZXingScannerView x:Name="ZXingScanner" 
                        HeightRequest="300"
                        IsScanning="{Binding IsScanning}" 
                        IsAnalyzing="{Binding IsAnalyzing}" 
                        Result="{Binding ScanningResult, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        ScanResultCommand="{Binding ScanResult}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="15" Grid.Row="2"/>

<zxing:ZXingDefaultOverlay TopText="Scan QR code" BottomText="Scan will happen automatically" Opacity="0.8" Margin="15" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

And in code, in OnAppearing I have this:

```
ZXingScanner.IsScanning = true;
ZXingScanner.IsAnalyzing = true;
```

I just want to see the live feed, scanning is working.

Extra Info:
On Android it's working fine
Test phone: iPhone 6 with iOS 12

***UPDATE:***
I see know that there is a huge delay in showing the live feed.
Sometimes it's a couple of seconds, but sometimes it takes minutes before the live feed is shown.

Comment: Have you added this line in the `FinishedLaunching` method of your `AppDelegate` class?

`ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();`

Comment: @Eifion Yes, I did.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the `ZXingScannerView`'s XAML:

```
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
```